# Vaadin spring boot extreme long startup

Tags: java, spring, web, spring-boot, vaadin

I am currently developing a little Vaadin Spring Boot application.
All works fine. I have my Spring Boot Application, that is auto-configured to detect the Vaadin UI and all of its Views.

When I start the Application in my IDE, the start Process takes max up to 5 secs.
But when I build my final JAR and run it from the Command Line, it takes extremely long.
Note: I started the JAR with the command: java -jar  at 11:50:00.

[LogFile on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YdVNKdrT)

The Startup process of Spring Boot finished at 12:02:19.
Then After 4 minutes, I reloaded the Website where the Application should run on.

From 12:06:00 until 12:07:40 the Vaadin Application loaded and I finally could access my Application.

I am not that familiar with Spring Boot, but what I definitely know is, that the Startup should not take that long.

Does anyone have an Idea, what could be changed that the the Application starts faster?

Computer Specs:

- Windows 7
- Intel Core i7-3630QM @2.40GHz
- 12 GB RAM
- 64-Bit
- Java 1.8.121 64Bit

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It should be much faster, what IDE do you use, and could you provide your computers basic specs ?

Comment: I edited my question and added Basic System Specs

Comment: Can you rule out, that this application is not somehow attempting to access some kind of resource, where access is denied at first and then some fallback is chosen?  So some timeout is happening while starting up? There should clearly be no reason for the uberjar to take longer than the IDE. If in doubt start it with a trace tool to see what is happening.

Comment: I copied the runnable Jar to different Locations: Desktop, AppData, Dokuments, .... Always the same. It takes extremely long.

Comment: Could you post your project to github or something?